# No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:,modulename:HelloWorldSessionBean,distinctname:]

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to develop my first EJB with an Example I found, I have the next mistake:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:,modulename:HelloWorldSessionBean,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@41408b80
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)
at $Proxy0.sayHello(Unknown Source)
at com.ibytecode.client.EJBApplicationClient.main(EJBApplicationClient.java:16)
```

I use JBOSS 7.1, and the code is this:
HelloWorld.java
    package com.ibytecode.business;

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface HelloWorld {

    public String sayHello();


}
```

HelloWorldBean.java
    package com.ibytecode.businesslogic;

```
import com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class HelloWorldBean
 */
@Stateless
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorld {

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public HelloWorldBean() {
}

public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello World !!!";
}
```

}

EJBApplicationClient.java:

```
package com.ibytecode.client;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.ibytecode.business.HelloWorld;
import com.ibytecode.businesslogic.HelloWorldBean;
import com.ibytecode.clientutility.ClientUtility;

public class EJBApplicationClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HelloWorld bean = doLookup();
    System.out.println(bean.sayHello()); // 4. Call business logic

}

 private static HelloWorld doLookup() {
        Context context = null;
        HelloWorld bean = null;
        try {
            // 1. Obtaining Context
            context = ClientUtility.getInitialContext();
            // 2. Generate JNDI Lookup name
            String lookupName = getLookupName();
            // 3. Lookup and cast
            bean = (HelloWorld) context.lookup(lookupName);

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bean;
    }


 private static String getLookupName() {
     /*
     The app name is the EAR name of the deployed EJB without .ear suffix.
     Since we haven't deployed the application as a .ear,
     the app name for us will be an empty string
     */
             String appName = "";

             /* The module name is the JAR name of the deployed EJB
             without the .jar suffix.
             */
             String moduleName = "HelloWorldSessionBean";

     /*AS7 allows each deployment to have an (optional) distinct name.
     This can be an empty string if distinct name is not specified.
     */
             String distinctName = "";

             // The EJB bean implementation class name
             String beanName = HelloWorldBean.class.getSimpleName();

             // Fully qualified remote interface name
             final String interfaceName = HelloWorld.class.getName();

             // Create a look up string name
             String name = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" +
                 distinctName    + "/" + beanName + "!" + interfaceName;

             return name;
         }


 }
```

ClientUtility.java 
     package com.ibytecode.clientutility;

```
 import java.util.Properties;
 import javax.naming.Context;
 import javax.naming.InitialContext;
 import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ClientUtility {

private static Context initialContext;

private static final String PKG_INTERFACES = "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming";

public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
    if (initialContext == null) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, PKG_INTERFACES);


        initialContext = new InitialContext(properties);
    }
    return initialContext;
}
```

}

properties.file:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

This is what I have. Why I have this?. Thanks so much. Regards

Comment: please write your code here , and we will tell how how to fix. Also tell me what server do you use, and which version is this server.

Comment: I have edit the question and I have posted the code. Regards and thanks

Comment: another question: client and server run on the same machine? did you imported in your client the jboss-client.jar?

Comment: I have the next jar when I run the configuration: jboss-client.jar, jboss-j2ee.jar and others jar as well and yes, they run in the same machine.

Comment: well in this hypotesys, since i suppose them to run on the same virtual machine you can use the Local and not Remote interface..

Comment: looks like your lookup wrong

Comment: I have changed the interface to local and nothing

Comment: @constantlearner, so what do you suggest?, how can I solve it?. Regards

Comment: Please print your  full jndi name

Comment: please check moduleName. see my answer :) (may by this is your project name)

Comment: I found the solution in this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11976412)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try with the following, I can't type it in a comment because it goes pretty long.

Seems that everything is fine, you can also leave the `@Remote` without any problem. I will also assume that you get the right path to your EJB: how to check it?

When you deploy it you should see in the server console something like this:

ejb:{app-Name}/{module-Name}/{distinct-Name}/{bean-Name}!{fullPath-remote-Interface}

EG: the first one is the one you are interested in (from [lookup](http://javafortheweb.blogspot.it/2013/06/ejb-smart-lookup.html))

```
java:global/MyBankLogicEAR/MyBankLogic/Account!main.IAccount
java:app/MyBankLogic/Account!main.IAccount
java:module/Account!main.IAccount
java:jboss/exported/MyBankLogicEAR/MyBankLogic/Account!main.IAccount
java:global/MyBankLogicEAR/MyBankLogic/Account
java:app/MyBankLogic/Account
java:module/Account
```

I will try to change the look up in the following way

```
final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

try {
    final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
    String appName = "";
    String moduleName = "jboss-firstbean";
    String distinctName = "";
    String beanName = "FirstBean";
    String interfaceFullName = "ejb.RemoteFirstBean";
    final String jndi = "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName;
    RemoteFirstBean statelessRemote = (RemoteFirstBean)context.lookup(jndi);
} catch (NamingException ex) {
    System.out.println("problems");
}
```

this is taken from [Accessing remote EJB on JBoss AS 7.1 from web application](http://javafortheweb.blogspot.it/2012/12/accessing-remote-ejb-on-jboss-as-71.html) , I also suggest you to check step 5 in very same page in order to understand if you need to configure other properties in your jboss-ejb-client.properties file..